# Python Character Encoding?

Tags: python

I'm not sure with the title I'm used, but basically I want to get rid off weird characters from the string. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# source: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4569

from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint as n2cp
import re

def substitute_entity(match):
    ent = match.group(3)

    if match.group(1) == "#":
        if match.group(2) == '':
            return unichr(int(ent))
        elif match.group(2) == 'x':
            return unichr(int('0x'+ent, 16))
    else:
        cp = n2cp.get(ent)

        if cp:
           return unichr(cp)
        else:
           return match.group()

def decode_htmlentities(string):
    entity_re = re.compile(r'&(#?)(x?)(\d{1,5}|\w{1,8});')
    return entity_re.subn(substitute_entity, string)[0]



test = ['<b>Blogger</b> in the Classroom - <b>Google</b>', 'Of\xef\xac\x81cial <b>Google   Blog</b>']
container = []

for i in test:
    container.append(decode_htmlentities(i))
print container

for i in test:
    print decode_htmlentities(i)
```

And here is the result:

```
['<b>Blogger</b> in the Classroom - <b>Google</b>', 'Of\xef\xac\x81cial <b>Google Blog</b>']

<b>Blogger</b> in the Classroom - <b>Google</b>
Ofﬁcial <b>Google Blog</b>
```

The Question:

Using the same function (decode_htmlentities()), why I get a different result when appending into a list and 'just' printing?

Here is the difference:

```
Of\xef\xac\x81cial <b>Google Blog</b> # output from list
Ofﬁcial <b>Google Blog</b> # output from print
```

Comment: Did you test your regex against the special characters?

Comment: No, I'm not test it. Why it has different result between printing and appending into a list?

Comment: Printing a list item in python parses differently than printing the actual list itself. See the answer below by Josh Lee.

Comment: What does it mean 'its failed' ? If you hit an exception please provide it.

Comment: What I want is the list like this: ['<b>Blogger</b> in the Classroom - <b>Google</b>', 'Ofﬁcial <b>Google Blog</b>']

Comment: @sopier: that's what you have. You just can't print a list like that. Note that in both cases there is the "weird character" "ﬁ", which is different than "fi" as 2 characters.

Comment: What, exactly, do you plan on doing with this list once it has the actual Unicode character instead of some “weird characters”?

Comment: @JoshLee I want to insert them into mysql database

Comment: Then just do it, but not as a list, but as distinct strings. And this way, it is perfectly fine, as `'\xef\xac\x81'` only looks that way, but it contains `ﬁ` as UTF8. Maybe you want to convert it to unicode first, turning it into something looking like `u'\fb01'` (but nevertheless still containing ﬁ), and inserting that.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a UTF-8 encoded string to a list, then printing the list will insert \x escaping. You can get the same result by calling `repr` on your string. Everything seems to be working correctly.

If you think printing a list should *not* escape the contents, then you’ll have to manually loop through the list. But if you see the correct value when the string is not in the list, then nothing changes when you add it to the list except how it reacts to `str`.

Perhaps you want to have proper Unicode characters instead of the UTF-8 bytes. So instead of this:

```
>>> s = '\xef\xac\x81'
>>> print [s]
['\xef\xac\x81']
```

You can see this:

```
>>> u = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> print [u]
[u'\ufb01']
>>> len(u)
1
>>> print u
ﬁ
```

Now you can manipulate the character as an atomic unit, which I hope is what you actually want; additionally, any tool which needs properly encoded characters will know what to do, since you’ve presented it with characters instead of bytes.

Comment: What I want is the list like this: ['<b>Blogger</b> in the Classroom - <b>Google</b>', 'Ofﬁcial <b>Google Blog</b>']

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you that’s what you’ve got?

Comment: Yes I **believe** you... I'm trying to query into mysql using those 'weird' characters and the result is `'ﬁ'` ... Thank you ... Too bad I don't have enough power to vote up your answers...

Answer (score 2):

"\xef\xac\x81" is the equivilent to `"ﬁ"` NOT `"fi"`. It is a trick to get the letters closer. So if you want to exclude those characters simply:

```
unicode(someoddstring, errors='ignore').encode('ascii')
```

or optionally try/except replace unicode characters and do a string replace of that sequence with "fi".

**EDIT:**
The character encoding is working as expected and should be stored that way in the string since "ﬁ" is not an ascii character and will always be represented in an escaped format.

If you simply want to make the list print out in the [ string, string ] format:

```
print "[",
for i in oddList:
  print i + ",",
print "]"
```

Comment: I want the 'ﬁ' in my list instead of "\xef\xac\x81"

Comment: Well you won't be able to get that. those encodings represent "ﬁ". "ﬁ" itself is not an ascii character and thus the data "ﬁ" is being correctly represented in the list. Everything is working correctly. If you simply want to print the list out see the edit.

Comment: @sopier It really is there. It is just represented in a different way.